# Compare XML String From Java Class When Item In ListView Is Clicked

Tags: java, android

The following code doesn't work, it is suppose to print "Found" when listview item product one is clicked.

However the following code returns an error and application closes, do I need to use the Context and if so how, I'm using get resource which finds the strings xml by id so therefore i don't really need context or do I, anyway what's wrong with my code? thanks in advanced.

XML file:

```
    <string-array name="titles_product">
    <item>ProductOne</item>
    <item>ProductTwo</item>
    <item>ProductThree</item>
    ...
```

Java Class

```
public class ListViewAdapterProduct extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
String[] productTitleArray;

    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Resources res = getResources();
            productTitleArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles_products);

            for (String productTitle : productTitleArray) 
            {
                if(productTitle.equals("ProductOne")) 
                    {   
                        Log.d("Msg", "Found");
                    }
                else
                    {
                        Log.d("Msg", "NOT Found");
                    }
            }
        }     
    });
```

Complete logcat:

```
    03-30 13:58:13.633: E/AndroidRuntime(775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 13:58:13.633: E/AndroidRuntime(775): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 13:58:13.633: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.twostarii.test.ListViewAdapterproduct$1.onClick(ListViewAdapterproduct.java:93)
03-30 13:58:13.633: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-30 13:58:13.633: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-30 13:58:13.633: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-30 13:58:13.633: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-30 13:58:13.633: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-30 13:58:13.633: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-30 13:58:13.633: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 13:58:13.633: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-30 13:58:13.633: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-30 13:58:13.633: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-30 13:58:13.633: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 13:58:16.173: I/Process(775): Sending signal. PID: 775 SIG: 9
03-30 13:58:17.063: D/dalvikvm(802): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 31K, 6% free 2424K/2576K, paused 36ms, total 38ms
03-30 13:58:17.073: I/dalvikvm-heap(802): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.190MB for 741952-byte allocation
03-30 13:58:17.203: D/dalvikvm(802): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3147K/3304K, paused 122ms, total 122ms
03-30 13:58:17.273: D/dalvikvm(802): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3147K/3304K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 69ms
03-30 13:58:17.643: D/dalvikvm(802): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 5% free 3605K/3768K, paused 70ms+3ms, total 120ms
03-30 13:58:17.846: D/libEGL(802): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
03-30 13:58:17.987: D/(802): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a166f18, tid 802
03-30 13:58:18.055: D/libEGL(802): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
03-30 13:58:18.063: D/libEGL(802): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
03-30 13:58:18.305: W/EGL_emulation(802): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-30 13:58:18.313: D/OpenGLRenderer(802): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: It prints " NOT Found"?

Comment: Please post the logcat output of the error. Are you sure that it crashes in the `onClick` method? (As an aside -- your loop will print one of "Found" or "NOT Found" for every element of the array; that probably isn't what you want.)

Comment: @Ted - i've updated my question to include the logcat

Comment: it's not the full logcat of the crash

Comment: @Marco, I have edited the post with another logcat, I think the issue is with how I'm calling the get resource since its in a class and not an activity, it works fine from an activity

Comment: What is line 93 of ListViewAdapterproduct.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get resource using `Context`...

```
Resources res = mContext.getResources();
```

Comment: thanks, it works except that for any button it will print "Found, Not Found, Not Found" despite whichever listview item I CLICK on, it's because of the FOR LOOP, when I click on product one is must just return FOUND, when I click on product 2 or 3 it must just return NOT FOUND in one line, if it was python I would create a function for each button but with java im not sure how I can do this, your answer is correct for my question but guess I got another problem now.

Comment: @TwoStarII - Ahead of your loop, declare a variable `boolean found=false;`. Then, in your loop, get rid of the `else` part of the `if` and after printing "Found", set `found=true;` and break out of the loop. After the loop, print "NOT Found" only if `found` is false.

Comment: @TwoStarII...I have seen your new question. I will ask you to put full `ListViewAdapterProduct` class code in the question.