# ListView Item OnItemClick crashing in ListView Adapter Class

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I've been trying to get my list view to work for quite some time now, I just changed my listener from onClick to onItemClick to handle listview items better but the app crashes once again, my code below, any help would be appreciated.

Class:

```
public class ListViewAdapterProduct extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);  

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){

        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        productTitleArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles_product);

        for (String productTitle : productTitleArray) 
        {
            if(productTitle.equals("productOne")) 
            {
            Log.d("Msg", "Found");
            }               
        else
            {
                Log.d("Msg", "Not Found");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My previous post:

[Compare XML String From Java Class When Item In ListView Is Clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744125/compare-xml-string-from-java-class-when-item-in-listview-is-clicked/22745015?noredirect=1#22745015)

**Logcat**:

```
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at com.twostarii.test.ListViewAdapterproduct.getView(ListViewAdapterproduct.java:91)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-30 16:40:39.027: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivityproduct extends MainActivity {


ListView list;
ListViewAdapterproduct adapter;
EditText editsearch;
String[] position;
String[] productTitles;
String[] productDescriptions;
int[] images={
        R.drawable.list_product_one, 
        R.drawable.list_product_two, 
        R.drawable.list_product_three,
    };


ArrayList<ClassproductList> arraylist = new ArrayList<ClassproductList>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    position = new String[] { "1", "2", "3"};

    Resources res = getResources();
    productTitles = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles_product);
    productDescriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions_product);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    for (int i = 0; i < position.length; i++)
    {
        ClassproductList wp = new ClassproductList(productTitles[i], productDescriptions[i],images[i]);
        arraylist.add(wp);
    }

    adapter = new ListViewAdapterproduct(this, arraylist);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

    editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            adapter.filter(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Crashes how? Is there a stacktrace you can provide?

Comment: I've posted logcat, it doesn't tell me anything hence I didn't post it, thanks for responding

Comment: `mContext` is null define it

Comment: @Ninja - please see my code above and advice on how to go about!

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem in `Context mContext;` is null

in your activity set `mContext = this;` so mContext would be the activity `context` you will be able to use the resources

this is the correct code :

since your already sent `this` in your adapter you need to catch it there

```
public class ListViewAdapterProduct extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
ArrayList<ClassproductList> arraylist;

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);  

 //add this
public ListViewAdapterProduct (Context mContext,ArrayList<ClassproductList> arraylist)
{
this.mContext = mContext;

this.arraylist = arraylist;
}
```

Comment: you sure ? i just edit my answer with example have you tried it ?

Comment: I see that, you're working within an activity however im working within a list adapter class: public class ListViewAdapterProduct extends BaseAdapter {

Comment: you need to pass the context from activity to the adapter please post the activity adapter call code , so the adapter will use the activity context , you cannot use context without activity

Comment: try now i've edit my answer also you can use the sent `arraylist ` from activity its already filled from activity so adapter can loop the elements

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the mContext, but you have not initialized it.

You can do this in the constructor of your adapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapterProduct extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;

    // the construcor that initializes the context
    public ListViewAdapterProduct(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }
    ...
```

However, the trace that you have posted, suggest that the problem is in your adapter's getView() method, on line 91. You should check that also.

```
ListViewAdapterproduct.getView(ListViewAdapterproduct.java:91)
```

Edit:

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In this line the adapter is null, you did not initialize it... (you set your adapter twice, first with null).
It is a good practise to define your variables locally, and make them class variable only when you actually need it. This way its harder to forget about initialization.

Comment: which is public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
NOTHING WRONG HERE, the problem came when I changed my onClick to onItemClick

Comment: Look at your logcat exception trace. The first line says the NullPointerException is in the 91th line of getView() method:)

Comment: the reason I posted my code above was to get detailed help, how do you suppose i go about this

Comment: I don't understand you. Is that logcat trace relevant or not? If yes, then look at the getView method, because that is where the Exception occures. If not, then why have you posted it?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !!!

I changed back from onItemClick (complicated to use with custom adapter) to onClick (simple to use with custom adapter) and applied:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    String mytitle=holder.title.getText().toString();

    if(mytitle.equals("ProductOne")){
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(mContext, ProductClass.ProductOne);
        mContext.startActivity(intent1);

        ...        

    }
}
```

Had to add:

```
String mytitle=holder.title.getText().toString();
```